# to hide custom workflow from another site alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need  to hide custom workflow list  for folders/documents present in " MyFiles " and other sites areas.Doing that from "show-site-workflow-modules.xml " with this configuration(code below), hides workflows from "workflows that I have started"  also,which is terribly wrong.

```
 <module>
             <id>General_Workflow</id>
             <description>Applies config based on site id</description>
             <evaluator type="site.module.evaluator">
                <params>
                   <sites>.*</sites>
                   <sitePresets>.*</sitePresets>   
                   <applyForNonSites>true</applyForNonSites>
                </params>
             </evaluator>
             <configurations>
              <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Workflow" replace="true">
            <!-- A list of workflow definitions that are NOT displayed in Share -->
            <hidden-workflows>
                <!-- Hide all Custom workflows -->
                <workflow name="customactiviti$xxxx" />
             </hidden-workflows>

            <!-- A list of workflow tasks that are NOT displayed in Share    -->
              <hidden-tasks>
                <task type="customwf:*" />
                 </hidden-tasks>

           </config>        
             </configurations>
          </module>


       <module>
             <id>xxx_Conditional_Workflow</id>
             <description>Applies config based on site id</description>
             <evaluator type="site.module.evaluator">
                <params>
                   <sites>xxx-xxx-xxx</sites>
                   <applyForNonSites>false</applyForNonSites>
                </params>
             </evaluator>
             <configurations>
              <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Workflow" replace="true">
            <!-- A list of workflow definitions that are NOT displayed in Share -->
            <hidden-workflows>

                <!-- Hide all WCM related workflows -->
               <workflow name="activiti$activitiAdhoc" />
                <workflow name="activiti$activitiInvitationModerated" />
                <workflow name="activiti$activitiInvitationNominated" />
                <workflow name="activiti$activitiInvitationNominatedAddDirect" />
                <workflow name="activiti$activitiParallelGroupReview" />
                <workflow name="activiti$activitiParallelReview" />
                <workflow name="activiti$activitiReview" />
                <workflow name="activiti$activitiReviewPooled" />
                <workflow name="activiti$publishWebContent" />
            </hidden-workflows>

            <!-- A list of workflow tasks that are NOT displayed in Share -->
            <hidden-tasks>
                <!-- Hide all WCM related tasks -->
                <task type="wcmwf:*" />
            </hidden-tasks>
        </config>

             </configurations> 
      </module>
```

Comment: please check this link. https://community.alfresco.com/thread/215555-custom-workflow-definition-must-be-hidden-for-other-sites-and-must-appear-on-only-specific-site

Comment: Thanks Sanjay but I have already followed the same link and this is causing the same issue mentioned in question above.!